# XQUERY select an element one after the conditional element that has been found

Tags: html, xml, xquery

I'm fairly new to XQuery so forgive me if this is extremely simple.

Essentially I'm searching a corpus of xml data for the word "has", and then I want to be able to return the word that follows immediately after "has" e.g. if the sentence was "has there been a fire?" I would like to return the word "there".

The XML corpus structure looks like this:

```
<s n="129">
                <w c5="NP0" hw="indonesia" pos="SUBST">Indonesia</w>
                <w c5="VHZ" hw="have" pos="VERB">has</w>
                <w c5="AJ0" hw="large" pos="ADJ">large</w>
                <w c5="NN2" hw="industry" pos="SUBST">industries</w>
                <c c5="PUN">,</c>
                <w c5="AV0" hw="recently" pos="ADV">recently</w>
                <w c5="VVN" hw="develop" pos="VERB">developed</w>
</s>
```

In this sample of data, I'd like the word "large" as it immediately follows "has".

My current XQuery code looks like this:

```
<hascount>
{
for $v in
    doc ("KS0.xml")/bncDoc/stext/div/u/s/w
where
    $v = "has"
return ($v)
}
</hascount>
```

It simply returns all the instances of has at the moment. How would I change this code to be able to perform what my intended task is above?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: (1) What is your XQuery engine? (2) Also, it is not clear if the word that follows immediately after "has" shall be in the same string or in the next `<w>` element.

Comment: w-elements are usually part of a TEI-document. It marks a word, so the probability that the thing searched for **is** the next-sibling w-element is high. Please confirm or deny the namespace of the document @Yash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code

```
    let $markup:=doc ("KS0.xml")

return $markup//w[matches(.,'^has$')]/following-sibling::w[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've found the answer to my own question.

This can be done by using XPath axis "following-sibling".

The implementation of this code in xquery would be:

```
<hascount>
{
for $v in
    doc ("KS0.xml")/bncDoc/stext/div/u/s/w
where
    $v = "has"
return ($v/following-sibling::*[1])
}
</hascount>
```

Comment: As you mention XPath, the whole `for .. return` is not necessary, a simple path expression with a predicate expression the condition you have in the `where` clause and a final step to select the sibling  `doc ("KS0.xml")/bncDoc/stext/div/u/s/w[. = 'has']/following-sibling::w[1]` suffices. For XQuery 3 it might be interesting to test whether windowed grouping performs better.